# Error trying to fetch your Careers profile. Please try again

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, developer-story

I was trying to **import my careers profile to my developer story** but it failed with this error

`Error trying to fetch your Careers profile. Please try again`

I tried again to no avail.

I had already completed the guided steps to choose my tech stack and state my current status as "actively looking", I'm not sure if that could cause some sort of conflict.

Please advise, I'm excited to use this new feature.

Comment: Ugh! Looking into it <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be fixed now.

When fetching your Careers profile, there was an enum value that wasn't recognized. This has been corrected.

Thanks for your report!

Comment: Thanx, I won't be able to verify until this evening FYI

Comment: Thanks, it worked.  Now time to tweak my story ; )